# integer programming: need help to formulate a constrain

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to formulate a constrain for my math model. the constrain goal is:

if A = 1 and B = 1 then C <= D
otherwise (A or B or both are 0) there is no constraint.

A and B are binary variables. C and D are integer numbers.

so far I was able to come up with this equation:

M(A - 1) - (B - 1) + C <= D   (M is a big big number)

this formulation does not hold when A = 1 and B = 0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It sounds like you are looking more for a formula or solution to your math problem, instead of a specific programming problem. Check out this other StackExchange site specifically for math: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps, first introduce a variable `X` representing logical and of `A` and `B`.

`X >= A + B - 1`

`X <= A`

`X <= B`

Then use `X` to express the inequality:

`C - M(1-X) <= D`